# What makes us say that Pythagoras theorem can be used in higher dimensions too?

Tags: geometry

Pythagoras theorem seems to be a geometric property of our Universe. It's a property that helps us find the distances between two points in coordinate geometry in one dimension, two dimensions and three dimensions. 
But what makes us comment that this geometrical property can too be used in higher dimensions too.

Comment: When we write the Pythagorean theorem in higher dimensions, we're actually still working in 2 dimensions, it's just a 2 dimensional subspace of a higher dimensional space. It would be pretty weird if 2D subspaces of higher dimensional spaces didn't behave like 2D space itself, no?

Comment: I'm going to quibble and say that it is *not* a geometric property of our physical Universe.  Space is curved, bent, and relativistic and we can't even *measure* it consistently much less apply the pythagorean theorem to it.  And Ian, above, is right about applying it to n-dimensions.  That's merely applying to two dimensions at a time.

Comment: I wonder if this question is more about the norm of the inner product than about Pythagoras.

Comment: @zahbaz I don't know about the norm of inner product but I meant the use of Pythagoras theorem for finding the Euclidean distance between two points. #fleablood but locally the Pythagoras theorem works where the space is flat but I agree not at the quantum scales or at the huge scales or relatively big scales compared to the local flat space where it can be used. #Ian yes I got it. Thanks all

Comment: @Ian So is it an 'approximation' that 2D spaces will behave same way in higher dimensions ? Or there's something that make it 'obvious' to happen as you said it will be pretty weird.

Comment: It is not approximate. It is just that two vectors make a plane, regardless of the dimension of the ambient space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sqrt {\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}^2 + z^2} = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$.  That's why.

Comment: Yes I surely can work with that as @Ian added in comments I'm working on a 2-d subspace of higher dimensional space.

Comment: So is it an approximation that 2D spaces will behave same way in higher dimensions ? Or there's something that make it obvious to happen ?

Comment: It's not an approximation.  It's a restriction to 2 dimensions at a time.  To find $|(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) - (0,0,0,0)|$ We see that $|x_4 - 0|$ is one leg of a triangle and $|(x_1,x_2,x_3) - (0,0,0)|$ is another.  This is *TWO* dimensions.  So $|(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) - (0,0,0,0)| = \sqrt{|(x_1,x_2,x_3) - (0,0,0)|^2 + x_4^2}$ is a 2-dimensional application.  To find $|(x_1,x_2,x_3) - (0,0,0)|$ is a 2 dimensional application. As is calculating  $|(x_1,x_2) - (0,0)|$.  And so on.

Comment: @user284090 A two dimensional subspace behaves like a two dimensional subspace. That's really all there is to it. I think you are mystifying it.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a theoretical extension of the three spatial dimensions in vector analysis.

So for $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ the magnitude or length of a vector is $$| x |=\sum_{i=1}^n  x_i=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$$

Comment: That's what I wanted to ask what make you use the Pythagorean theorem to get to the result that you added in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Property of our universe" - no.

Here is the thing. There is math, and there is empirical science. When you talk about math, it's somewhat "simple", you take formulas and derive more of them. Pythagoras theorem lives in math and can be extended there.

As for the universe, let me give you a related term here: *euclidean distance*. The euclidean distance between two points in an euclidean space is $d = \sqrt{\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i - y_i)^2}$. Sounds familiar, right?

Now realize that there are non-euclidean spaces, in which this does not hold, and in which pythagoras theorem also doesn't.

When you go with "property of your universe", what I hear is "something that we measured by empirical methods". We didn't. We evaluated that the theorem works, but it does not come from empirism.

And the most important thing: *it is not true* for our universe. It works for you when you measure the angles of a house or the like, but especially when you look at the General Theory of Relativity, you find the problems with this. Space-time is bent by mass and thus not *flat*.

For more on this, see https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-proof-that-space-isnt-Euclidean

Thus, this is *not at all* a property of our universe. This is a mathematical property of a mathematically defined space.

Oh, and if you consider time as a dimension, you need to go into Minkowski spaces, which makes things... complicated.